# List equality of a custom class

Tags: c#, list, comparison, equality

I have a class `A`, which holds a string property and overwrites `Equals` for equality testing.

```cs
public class A
{
    public string Prop { get; }

    public A(string val)
    {
        Prop = val;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return obj is A arg && (Prop == arg.Prop);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return base.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

I also have a class `B` which has a `List<A>` as property:

```cs
public class B
{
    public IReadOnlyList<A> Prop { get; }

    public B(IReadOnlyList<A> val)
    {
        Prop = val;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return base.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

I wanna be able to compare to instances of B for equality and order.
How can I write the Equals method in B by not rewriting the same code I wrote in A?
Is there a way to reuse the A Equals?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to implement `IComparable<T>` (and/or `IComparable`) so that you can sort your items?

Comment: Read about [SequenceEqual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal?view=netframework-4.8) linq method

Comment: Side note: Your current GetHashCode method overrides for A and B are not suitable if two instances of A or two instances of B can be equal. Look up and read the rules for implementing a `GetHashCode` override with respect to equality in the documentation for `Object.GetHashCode`...

Comment: Do you want to compare the lists taking into consideration the order, or ignoring the order of the elements? Ignoring the order is harder.

Comment: Second side note: Make sure the content of the collection represented by `B.Prop` is not mutable/not modified elsewhere. If the collection instance in `Prop` (passed as `val` argument to the constructor) where to be modified at a later time during your program execution (after creating a `B` instance with that collection), the whole equality and hash code thingamabob for your `B` class would fall apart like a house of cards, potentially causing weird, unforeseen and possibly catastrophic side effects depending on how your program works with `B` instances...

Comment: @TheodorZoulias The order is relevant. 3,2,1 and 2,3,1 should result in false when being compared.

Comment: @Kyu96 are you intending to use the class as the key of a `Dictionary`? If you do then it is mandatory to implement `GetHashCode()` in a way that equal instances have equal hashCodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementing `Equals` for a list can be done by using the `SequenceEquals` method (from `System.Linq` namespace), which ensures that each item in one list equals the item at the same index in the other list.

One thing you might consider changing, however is your implementation of `GetHashCode`. This method should return the same number if two items are equal (though it's not guaranteed that two items with the same hash code are equal). Using `base.GetHashCode()` does not meet this requirement, since the `base` is `object` in this case; according to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.gethashcode?view=netframework-4.8), *"hash codes for reference types are computed by calling the Object.GetHashCode method of the base class, which computes a hash code based on an object's reference"*, so objects only return the same HashCode if they refer to the exact same object.

The `HashCode` should be based on the same properties used to determine equality, so in this case we want to use `Prop.GetHashCode()` for class `A`, and we want to aggregate the hashcode for all the items in `Prop` for class `B`.

Here's one way the classes could be refactored:

```
public class A : IEquatable<A>
{
    public string Prop { get; }

    public A(string val)
    {
        Prop = val;
    }

    public bool Equals(A other)
    {
        if (other == null) return false;
        return Prop == other.Prop;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return Equals(obj as A);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Prop.GetHashCode();
    }
}

public class B : IEquatable<B>
{
    public IReadOnlyList<A> Prop { get; }

    public B(IReadOnlyList<A> val)
    {
        Prop = val;
    }

    public bool Equals(B other)
    {
        if (other == null) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;
        if (Prop == null) return other.Prop == null;
        return other.Prop != null && Prop.SequenceEqual(other.Prop);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return Equals(obj as B);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Prop?.Aggregate(17,
            (current, item) => current * 17 + item?.GetHashCode() ?? 0)
                ?? 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on your `GetHashCode` implementation for B? Why not just: `return (Prop != null ? Prop.GetHashCode() : 0);` ?

Comment: Sure, it's because `Prop` is a `List` type, and i believe that uses the default reference implementation, which wouldn't work for this class. So this example uses the hash code of all the objects in the list, so that two lists that contain the same items will return the same hash code.

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** My first version assumed `B` is derived from `A`.

1. `A.Equals`:

If `A` is not sealed, `obj is A ...` can return a false positive if different types are compared. So the corrected version:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    return obj is A other
        && this.Prop == other.Prop
        && this.GetType() == other.GetType(); // not needed if A is sealed
}
```

2. `A.GetHashCode`:

`base.GetHashCode` will return different hash codes for different but equal instances, which is wrong. Derive the hashcode from self properties instead. If `Prop` acts like some ID, then simply return `Prop.GetHashCode()`

3. `B.Equals`:

```
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return obj is B other
            && this.Prop.SequenceEqual(other.Prop) // will re-use A.Equals
            && this.Prop.GetType() == other.Prop.GetType() // not needed if different IReadOnlyList types are ok
            && this.GetType() == other.GetType(); // not needed if B is sealed
    }
```

4. `B.GetHashCode`:

You can aggregate the hash codes of `A` instances. Here I use a simple XOR but if the same items can often come in a different order you can come up with something more fancy.

```
return Prop.Aggregate(0, (h, i) => h ^ i.GetHashCode());
```

Comment: With regard to point 4: If two instances of B can be equality compared and found to be equal, then what you said about A.GetHashCode applies in an equivalent manner also to B. B.GetHashCodes has to be overridden so that it returns the same hash code for two B instances that are considered to be equal. Not overriding B.GetHashCode would be wrong.

Comment: @elgonzo: If two `B` instances are equal, then their base `Equals` already returned true according to point 3 so it will work.

Comment: I was talking about B.GetHashCode (your point 4), not about B.Equals...

Comment: I know. _"so that it returns the same hash code for two B instances that are considered to be equal"_ Just think of it, hash code is a 32 bit integer. Collisions are expected even for strings longer than two chars. Actually returning a constant zero hash code also works. It turns a dictionary into a slow sequentially read collection but works. The only problem if you return different hash codes for equal instances as in the original post because then an already existing item will not be found in the dictionary,

Comment: What are you talking about here? Two object instances that are considered to be equal have to return the `same hash code`. Why are you starting to talk about collisions? We are not talking about hash codes of unequal instances, but about hash codes of equal instances...

Comment: But this was my first comment about. Due to point 3 it will work.

Comment: No, it won't. Two instances considered equal but returning different hash codes will not be deemed equal by collections like a dictionary (otherwise, what would be the point of hash codes anyway?) You said so yourself in your last comment...

Comment: But how do they return different hash codes? `A.Prop` will be the same.

Comment: B instances have each a **collection** of multiple A instances, they are not deriving from A. How will B.GetHashCode account for that if not overridden properly?

Comment: No, it can't. Again, B instances have each a **collection** of multiple A instances and which are participating in B's definition of equality. I even wrote the word "collection" in bold in my last comment. How is your last comment even making a sliver of sense with respect to this?

Comment: Oh got it. I assumed `B : A` for some reason

Comment: Thank you for your note. I was blind for long minutes. After fixing `B` members I unhid the answer again.

Answer (score 1):

Linq contains a useful method to compare collections: [SequenceEqual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal?view=netcore-2.2)

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    if (!(obj is B other))
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (this.Prop == null || other.Prop == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return this.Prop.SequenceEqual(other.Prop);
}
```

Also, implement `IEquatable<T>` when you override Equals.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    if(!(obj is B))
    {
        return false;
    }

    var b = obj as B;

    if(b.Prop.Count != this.Prop.Count)
    {
        return false;
    }

    for(var i =0; i < Prop.Count; i++)
    {
        if (!Prop.ElementAt(i).Equals(b.Prop.ElementAt(i)))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```